# How to connect localhost database to another server database and insert form value using codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli

```
<?php
$active_group = 'default';

$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'campus';
$db['default']['password'] = 'Mac@123';
$db['default']['database'] = 'campusnew';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE;


$db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "101.51.150.42";
$db['otherdb']['username'] = 'software';
$db['otherdb']['password'] = 'Lmsnew';
$db['otherdb']['database'] = 'lmsnew';
$db['otherdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
$db['otherdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['otherdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['otherdb']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['stricton'] = TRUE;
```

model function

```
public function newusersignin()
{ 
    $DB2 = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
    $firstName=$this->input->post('firstName');
    $lastName=$this->input->post('lastName');
    $timezone=$this->input->post('timezone');
    $fullname=$firstName.' '.$lastName;
    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    $phone=$this->input->post('phone');
    $ip_address=$this->input->ip_address();
    $institutional=$this->input->post('institutional');
    $pass=$firstName.mt_rand(1,100);
    $username=$email;
    $password=$this->hash($pass);
    $insertnewuser= array('name' =>$fullname,'email'=>$email,'phone'=>$phone,'username'=>$username,'password'=>$password,'usertype'=>'ClgAdmin','create_date'=>date('y-m-d H:i:s'),'create_userID'=>1,'create_username'=>'campus','systemadminactive'=>0,'timezone'=>$timezone,'status'=>1 );
    $this->db->insert('admin',$insertnewuser);
    $DB2->insert('admin',$insertnewuser);
}
```

In this question I am simply create two database connection one is for `localhost` and another one is `IP` which is hosted on different server. Now, what happen when I am going to insert form data in my `IP` Server then it throw an error and i.e.

> > Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

I don't know why this happen? How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: MySQL connection driver does not get any meaningful server at the location of localhost. So use change `'localhost';` to ip `'127.0.0.1';`

Comment: @Dlk no it's the remote connection which is not working. Read the question again.

Comment: So, How can I do that @ADyson

Comment: Avi if this remote database is hosted on another server then probably connections are blocked from external sites. You likely need to set a rule to allow inbound mysql connections from wherever your PHP code is hosted. Precisely what you must do will depend on the type of server, the hosting settings etc.

Comment: Duplicate [Datebase error mysqli::real\_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused codeingiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501299/datebase-error-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-connection-refused-codeingi)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doubling everything in two arrays, can you check against the URL?

Just change the localhost to be more specific as to which db you need to connect too

```
$is_local = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
if (strpos($is_local, 'localhost') !== false) {
    // LOCAL
    $db_name = "db_name";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "root_pass";
    $db_host = "localhost";
} else {
    // OTHER
    $db_name = "db_name_2";
    $db_user = "root_live";
    $db_pass = "root_pass_live";
    $db_host = "mysql.live.com";
}
```

Then your connection code is always the same from then

Comment: I seriously hope you don't routinely use the "root" account for your web applications to access the database, as this example suggests...

Answer (score 0):

**Database Configuration**

CodeIgniter has a config file that lets you store your database connection values (username, password, database name, etc.). The config file is located at application/config/database.php. You can also set database connection values for specific environments by placing database.php in the respective environment config folder.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

**Inserting Data**

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'My title',
    'name' => 'My Name',
    'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: What have you changed and why? Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Your database configuration and methodology given above are correct. All you have to do is allow remote connection for your database on your server. If you are using CPanel, you can browse to "Remote MySQL" and add access host. Add your ISP IP address to allow only your computer or "%" for any computer to access.